# linkedin web crawler in c#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, linkedin-api

I want to pull data from linkedin using webbrowser to Chromium Embedded Framework
when i tried to use webbrowser then it gives scriping error i tired to manage cookies

```
[DllImport("wininet.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool InternetSetCookie(string lpszUrlName, 
                                     string lpszCookieName, string lpszCookieData);
```

and setting values which didnt worked.

then i tried to use cefshapr

i can pull some data 
but cant login automatically

any help would appreciated thank you a lot :)

Comment: Please include more details of your approach and all the relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100 % sure, but I think this P/Invoke call will set a cookie to your installed IE's cookie jar. `WebBrowser` instances have their own cookie jars. I think the best way for you to set a cookie is to just insert a `document.cookie = 'something'` script within the document's body, because you have full control over its DOM and scripting environment, so it will be as if the application set the cookie itself.

Since you are already playing with `WebBrowser` you can probably just stick with it, unless you find the pages you want to look at are broken in IE at which point your further investigation into CEF and a new, more focused question on SO will be helpful.